# Do we need visited flags when applying BFS on a tree?

Tags: graphs, trees, search-algorithms

Do we need visited boolean flags when applying `BFS` on a tree ?

```
/**
 * Traverse the grap as BFS
 * 
 * @param {String}   $vertex              the key of the source vertex
 * @param {Function} $getAdjacentCallback to get the adjacent verticies
 * @param {Funcrion} $visitCallback       called when a vertex is visisted for the first time
 */
function bfs($vertex, $getAdjacentCallback, $visitCallback) {

  $visited = [];
  $queue = new SplQueue();
  $queue->enqueue($vertex);

  while(!$queue->isEmpty()) {

    $currentVertex = $queue->dequeue();

    // Is unvisited
    if (!isset($visited[$currentVertex])) {
      $visited[$currentVertex] = true;
      $visitCallback($currentVertex);
    }

    // Foreach adjacent vertices, find one of the unvisited adjacent vertcies if any
    foreach ($getAdjacentCallback($currentVertex) as $adjacentVertex) {

      // Is unvisited
      if (!isset($visited[$adjacentVertex])) {
        $queue->enqueue($adjacentVertex);
      }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: The question lacks some context. Do you have any particular implementation of BFS in mind, one which uses visited flags that you would like to get rid of? Please update the question with this information.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus a basic implementation to visit all the nodes but in a tree (acyclic connected graph)

Comment: @YuvalFilmus my code is added

Comment: Have you tried removing them and seeing what happens?

Comment: Yes, seems fine. I am wondering if I miss any case

Comment: Have you tried proving that the modified algorithm works in your case? This is how we know for sure whether some property always holds. Try to show that the algorithm without the flags behaves exactly like the algorithm with the flags (if that's true).

Comment: Please get rid of the source code and replace it with ideas, concise pseudo code and arguments of correctness. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/64/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/390/) for related meta discussions.